# Initialize static variables of Interface via Enum

Tags: java, java-8, static-initialization

I am trying to understand the below behavior, all I am trying is to initialize the static variable of interface via enum method.

```
enum Hello {
    ProfileResolver();

    public Hello resolve() {
        System.out.println("resolve method called!!!!");
        return ProfileResolver;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Resolver{
  Hello hello = Hello.ProfileResolver.resolve(); // this should called when creating an instace of any implementation
}
```

Implentation class like below

```
public class Impl implements Resolver{
}
```

and now if

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
   Resolver resolver = new Impl();
}
```

Now at this point I was expecting just before object initialization of `Impl` object, hello variable of Interface must initialize and resolve method called, but it is not.
And when I declare Resolver as class instead of inteface, it is working as expected.
Can anyone help me try to understand ?

Comment: The variable `hello` in your interface is `static` and `final`. These modifiers are implicit for properties in an interface.

Comment: @ernest_k,  i know static and final are implicit in interface, but i am trying to understand is when and how this constant "hello" gets initialized , as per my understanding as soon as class is loaded first static variables and static blocks run so in this case when i am trying to create object of Impl class , which implements Resolver interface. So did not "resolve" method should be called as this is called when initializing "hello"  prior to creation of Impl object ??

Comment: Because this is sensitive to your runtime, please tag your question with the compiler/IDE you're using as well as the actual Java version (if not Java 8)

Comment: @Sebastian, i tried to debug but resolve method is not called, but as per your suggestion it tried to reference hello variable in implementing class like `private Hello implHello = hello; and it worked.                                                                                                                 JVM  version : openjdk version "1.8.0_282", Can you tell me what info i am missing here?  and if it is specific to JIT optimization , did'nt it inappropriate as it is  affecting end user code or logic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the specified triggers for static initialization of types in Java. This is from the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

> **12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs**
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
>
> When a class is initialized, its superclasses are initialized (if they have not been previously initialized), as well as any superinterfaces (§8.1.5) ***that declare any default methods*** (§9.4.3) (if they have not been previously initialized). Initialization of an interface does not, of itself, cause initialization of any of its superinterfaces.
>
> A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface.
>
> Invocation of certain reflective methods in class Class and in package java.lang.reflect also causes class or interface initialization.
>
> A class or interface will not be initialized under any other circumstance.

A careful analysis indicates that your code does not meet any of the requirements for the `Resolver` interface's static initialization to be carried out...

- `new Impl()` causes the initialization of `Impl`, but this does not cause the intialization of `Resolver`, because `Resolver` does not have any default methods (see my bold-italic text emphasis).
- Nothing requires that a reference to the `Resolver` type should trigger initialization
- The way to cause this code to trigger `Resolver`'s initialization is to either add a default method to it (no point in this), or to read its static variables:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Resolver resolver = new Impl();
      System.out.println(Resolver.hello); //causes initialization
  }
  ```

If you're using `Hello hello = Hello.ProfileResolver.resolve();` to trigger some intended side-effects through the `resolve()` method, then [please don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723562/5761558).

Comment: Thanks!! ernest_k, it worked as soon as default method added in interface.